# Hide select dropdown in IE 11 with alloy ui in liferay

Tags: css, liferay, internet-explorer-11, alloy-ui

I´m using liferay 6.2 with alloy ui and I´m trying to hide the arrow from the dropdown of a select in IEE 11 with :

```
   select::-ms-expand {
   display: none !important;
  }
```

I have also tried

```
   .aui select::-ms-expand {
   display: none !important;
  }
```

But I check the resources , I see the styles in the CSS  but when I inspect the select element the style is not present .

Comment: which files are you editing for this?

Comment: A css that loads on the target page .

Comment: come on. "a css". What kind of answer do you expect? "you need to change *another* css"?

Comment: Please post all the relevant code. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that liferay was configured to launch the portlet on IEE9 and the code I was trying is only supported from IEE10 .